# Are the two top network posts sections supposed to match?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, network-profile, top-network-posts

Currently there are two places you can view a user's top network posts.

You can view top posts on a user's site profile:

> [image: site profile]

You can also view top posts in a user's network profile, the difference here being, the top questions are separate from top answers:

> [image: network profile]

Are these two sections supposed to be the same with the same data displayed, or are they two different sections?

The reason I am asking this is because of a discussion I had reguarding the following questions:
[Top posts taken from hidden communities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277279/top-posts-taken-from-hidden-communities)

The problem stated in that question is that top posts from hidden communities are hidden from the side site profile section, yet not from the network profile top section. I see this as a bug since I though the two sections are supposed to be the same, and just used as another way to view the same data. Yet after having [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/292830/297762), I am confused.

To quote from the other user:

> Well, there seems to be some confusion over "Top Network Posts", which is referring specifically to the "Communities" and "Top Network Posts" sections on the left side of your profile:
>
> ...
>
> That is, this setting affects what others see when they look at your site profiles, but it is not related to the network profile top posts list.
>
> ...
>
> So, this feature is actually working correctly and as described, it just wasn't designed to do what you thought it was...this is a feature request that I stand behind, but it is not a bug as tagged

Is this really true? Are the two sections really separate entities? Should the fact they don't match be a feature request and not a bug?

When you hide communities, the disappear from the both the site side profile communities section, as well as the network profile accounts section. So, is this just a nice added feature that the communities section is in sync, and the top posts section is missing this bonus feature, or is the communities section working how all sections are supposed to work, while the top post section has a bug since it doesn't function the same way?

Depending on whether they are considered to be the same or different sections, I would then ask if it is appropriate to use the [top-network-posts](/questions/tagged/top-network-posts) tag for questions pertaining to both of the sections?