# Accounts (on the activity tab) links to network profile even if the community is hidden

Tags: bug, network-profile, hidden-communities, activity

We know that if a community is hidden, one can not see the "Network Profile" link except moderators. But I've found that one can still find "Network Profile" link from accounts link on activity tab.

For example, (Though I don't like hiding communities)  I've just hidden a community - Information Security. Now if you go through [my profile](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/94977/) on Internet Security, you won't be able to see the "Network Profile" link:

> [image]

**But the "Accounts" link from the ["Activity"](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/94977/pandya?tab=topactivity) tab will give you my network profile link!**

[image: screenshot showing the clickable account link.]

So, in such cases, not showing the "Network Profile" link to normal users is pointless given that the accounts tab contains a link to the Network Profile.

Hence, I suggest removing the network profile link from "Accounts" on the "Activity" tab as it is already available for the profile owner through the "view more" option underneath Accounts.

Comment: I'd guess that this is visible for you, and you only, as I cannot see it. Might also take a bit to kick in.

Comment: @Seth - it's not just the user. I can see the link too.

Comment: Yep, I can see the link

Comment: I think you have this backwards.  "Information Security" is hidden; your other profiles are not.  Therefore, visitors can navigate from IS to other sites, but there's no link from other sites (including the network-wide profile) to IS.